# Module Federation - Integrations

Tags: webpack, module, bundler, webpack-module-federation

How can you `integrate` and `leverage` existing **module bundlers or build systems** (e.g., **Webpack**, **Rollup**) with Module Federation to create a unified and efficient build pipeline for complex applications?